# Нужна ли проверка на наличие записи при добавлении новых в MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, json, qt, qnetworkrequest

Имеются таблицы systems, coords с уникальным полем id. Часто бывают запросы на добавление записи с уже имеющимся id, пока проверки нету то бд сама проверит и вернет исключение, вопрос в том что нужно ли дописывать проверку на наличие id или все оставить на реализацию в самой бд. По сути выполним свою проверку, но бд потом выполнит свою все равно и думаю какое то влияние на загруженность да будет.

Немного пояснений: данные берутся с апи и добавляются в таблицу если их нет.

Как выглядит обработчик данных

```
void EdsmApiParse::getResponse(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug() << "Response";
    // Если ошибки отсутсвуют
    if(!reply->error()){
        QJsonArray document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).array();
        db.connectToDataBase();
        for(auto el:document)
        {

            data.push_back(el.toObject()["id"].toVariant());
            data.push_back(el.toObject()["name"].toVariant());
            data.push_back(el.toObject()["bodyCount"].toVariant());
            data.push_back(el.toObject()["distance"].toVariant());
            qDebug() <<data[0].toInt()<<data[1].toString()<<data[2].toInt() <<data[3].toFloat();
            db.insertIntoSystems(std::move(data));

            data.push_back(el.toObject()["id"].toVariant());
            data.push_back(el.toObject()["coords"].toObject()["x"].toVariant());
            data.push_back(el.toObject()["coords"].toObject()["y"].toVariant());
            data.push_back(el.toObject()["coords"].toObject()["z"].toVariant());
            db.insertIntoCoords(std::move(data));
        }

    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

и отправка запроса

```
bool DataBaseJob::insertIntoCoords(const QVariantList data)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO coords (id, x, y, z)"
                  "VALUES (:id, :x, :y, :z)");
    query.bindValue(":id", data[0].toInt());
    query.bindValue(":x", data[1].toFloat());
    query.bindValue(":y", data[2].toFloat());
    query.bindValue(":z", data[3].toFloat());
    if(!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "error insert into coords";
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Оставить на БД. отдельный запрос на проверку во первых лишняя трата ресурсов. во вторых, если одновременно вставку может производить более чем один процесс то может возникнуть состояние гонки: Между тем моментом как вы проверили, что записи нет и самой вставкой кто то другой может успеть вставить запись и вы получите ровно такое же исключение из за дублирования. техники защиты от этого есть, но это еще большее усложнение и трата ресурсов. P.S. если информация о дубле (исключение) не нужна, то можно использовать `insert ignore` что бы БД не бросала ошибку при наличии записи

Comment: Ошибка, вернее, её ожидание - вообще неправильно, не должно быть ошибок. Ведь существование записи - ситуация совершенно штатная. То есть нужно выполнить попытку вставки и быть уверенным, что после неё нужная запись, на которую потом надо сослаться - есть, и пофиг, вставилась она сейчас или была раньше. Так что INSERT IGNORE или INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE / REPLACE (в зависимости от логики) - правильное решение. А потом - INSERT .. SELECT, чтобы получить референсные значения индексов по заданным литералам.

Comment: Не совсем согласен с @Akina. Предпочитаю воспринимать исключения как ещё один вариант возврата из метода, но по другому пути. Более того, в данном случае исключение - как раз таки штатное поведение, ибо ожидается либо положительный результат (запись добавлена), либо отрицательный (запись уже есть). Лично я за перехват данного исключения и его обработку (например при дебаге выводить в лог "запись уже есть")

Comment: @Sheridan Получение любого результата - что положительного, что отрицательного,- это штатное поведение, которое должно различаться только возвращаемым значением. Действие выполнено. А если не удалось соединиться с сервером, не существует указанной таблицы, нет прав на чтение или запись таблицы и т.п. - вот это уже события нештатные, которые должны порождать ошибку. А валить в обработчик ошибок всё подряд - и результаты ожидаемые, и неожиданные,- это как-то неправильно.

Comment: @Akina ну не скажите. Отсутствие связи с сервером - штатное поведение если серверов много и надо попробовать следующий из списка. Нет прав тоже вполне штатное поведение и тоже можно автоматом обработать (например таки повысить права)

Comment: @Sheridan *Отсутствие связи с сервером - штатное поведение если серверов много и надо попробовать следующий из списка. Нет прав тоже вполне штатное поведение и тоже можно автоматом обработать (например таки повысить права)* Это если и штатные ситуации - то они штатные внешне для рассматриваемого процесса. Данный же процесс ориентирован на то, что он обратится к конкретному серверу и будет иметь все необходимые права, задача процесса - только выполнение операции согласованной записи данных в таблицы БД.

Comment: А проблемами выбора сервера, проверки связи с ним и наличия прав будет заниматься внешняя процедура, которая потом, когда всё будет тип-топ, вызовет эту. И вот для той внешней процедуры описанные состояния - действительно штатные.